# fastify-openapi-glue FastifyError: ... strict mode: unknown keyword: "example"

Tags: node.js, fastify, fastify-swagger

I have upgraded from Fastify v3 to v4, which I use to serve mock apis based on OpenAPI/swagger by using the plugin `fastify-openapi-glue`.

Since the upgrade, I receive the error `FastifyError [Error]: Failed building the validation schema for POST: /contract, due to error strict mode: unknown keyword: "example"` which is, because there is no example in the schema and [openapi-glue documentation](https://github.com/seriousme/fastify-openapi-glue/blob/master/docs/AJVstrictMode.md) suggests to disable ajv strict mode (also disabling strictSchema should be sufficient in that case).

With the switch from Fastify 3 to 4 these options need to go into the Fastify options, which I did. Additionally added them to our own plugin, which is another place where it can be defined.
Still it seems the options are being ignored, and I do not know why.

I created a reproduction with stackblitz (awesome btw :D, nodejs in the browser)
[stackblitz:fastify4-upgrade-openapi-glue-issue?file=plugins%2Fswagger.js%3AL28](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fastify4-upgrade-openapi-glue-issue?file=plugins%2Fswagger.js%3AL28)

Install dependencies with `npm install` and then run it with `npm start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide the [`--options` flag to fastify-cli](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli/#options) or it will not load the config.

So change the `package.json`

```json
{
  "start": "fastify start --options app.js",
}
```

And the `ajv.customOptions` stuff goes on `app.js` only.

Comment: Oh my gosh .. I have `--options` in the original implementation and removed it, because I misinterpreted the documentation "Use custom options" (aka if you provide --options, cli options are being used, others ignored), since we have some cli arg options aswell.